# Best way to handle error and success messages copy texts from back-end?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, server

I have an Android application and right now I am managing error and success messages in strings.xml resource file. Now in case if I want to change these messages I need to make changes in strings.xml file and give an app update in play-store, which is a bit overhead. Instead, I want these messages to be managed from server side (back-end) so that they can be changed without any update. Can anyone please suggest me the best way to achieve this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/gettingstarted/creating-guestbook

Comment: Hey you can manage from the server side also eg.like when you hit to API you get response inside that if this API success then it will give success code and message and response data.If it fail then you get error code and error message from server then parse it and display in toast or as per your convenience.

Comment: for API hitting what you use Volley or Retrofit ???

Comment: I am using volley.

Comment: @AlexT. that doesn't seem related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use Volley then this is helpfil for you

VolleyError is really just an extended Exception, so Exception.getMessage() likely wouldn't return what you are looking for unless you override the parsing methods for parsing your VolleyError in your extended Request class. A really basic way to handle this would be to do something like:

```
//In your extended request class
@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
        if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
                VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                volleyError = error;
            }

        return volleyError;
    }
}
```

If you add this to your extended Request classes, your getMessage() should at least not return null. I normally don't really bother with this, though, since it's easy enough to do it all from within your onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) method.

You should use a JSON library to simplify things -- I use Gson for example or you could use Apache's JSONObjects which shouldn't require an additional external library. The first step is to get the response JSON sent from your server as a String (in a similar fashion to what I just demonstrated), next you can optionally convert it to a JSONObject (using either apache's JSONObjects and JsonArrays, or another library of your choice) or just parse the String yourself. After that, you just have to display the Toast.

Here's some example code to get you started:

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     String json = null;

     NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
     if(response != null && response.data != null){
         switch(response.statusCode){
             case 400:
                  json = new String(response.data);
                  json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                  if(json != null) displayMessage(json);
                  break;
             }
            //Additional cases
     }
}

public String trimMessage(String json, String key){
    String trimmedString = null;

    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        trimmedString = obj.getString(key);
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return trimmedString;
}

//Somewhere that has access to a context
public void displayMessage(String toastString){
    Toast.makeText(context, toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but it will not work in my case since I have custom messages for different error and success response. e.g In change password success response I am showing "Your password has been changed. Now if I want to change it to "Password updated." then what?

Comment: So you get that string from server  Success response message so parse it and display. whatever change request come from business then changes only at server side don't need to do anything at android side.

Comment: That would require changes in all the API contracts (response json), which I don't think is an ideal way for this much huge application.